# How to find out when an Oracle table was updated the last time

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface

Can I find out when the last INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement was performed on a table in an Oracle database and if so, how?

A little background: The Oracle version is 10g. I have a batch application that runs regularly, reads data from a single Oracle table and writes it into a file. I would like to skip this if the data hasn't changed since the last time the job ran.

The application is written in C++ and communicates with Oracle via OCI. It logs into Oracle with a "normal" user, so I can't use any special admin stuff.

Edit: Okay, "Special Admin Stuff" wasn't exactly a good description. What I mean is: I can't do anything besides SELECTing from tables and calling stored procedures. Changing anything about the database itself (like adding triggers), is sadly not an option if want to get it done before 2010.

Comment: Yes... the 2010 comment is about the slowness of your DBAs I take it?

Comment: Well, kind of. They are slow, but as I said in an earlier comment I understand them. If there is a problem with this database it get's really ugly, really fast. You can get stuff in there, but only after it was analyzed to hell by a bunch of people.

Comment: As I can't comment on answers yet (I'm new here), I wanted to comment that I've found that CDC has been removed from Oracle 12c to push people to buy GoldenGate.
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/deprecated.htm#UPGRD60083

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Since you are on 10g, you could potentially use the `ORA_ROWSCN` pseudocolumn.  That gives you an upper bound of the last SCN (system change number) that caused a change in the row.  Since this is an increasing sequence, you could store off the maximum `ORA_ROWSCN` that you've seen and then look only for data with an SCN greater than that.

By default, `ORA_ROWSCN` is actually maintained at the block level, so a change to any row in a block will change the `ORA_ROWSCN` for all rows in the block.  This is probably quite sufficient if the intention is to minimize the number of rows you process multiple times with no changes if we're talking about "normal" data access patterns.  You can rebuild the table with `ROWDEPENDENCIES` which will cause the `ORA_ROWSCN` to be tracked at the row level, which gives you more granular information but requires a one-time effort to rebuild the table.

Another option would be to configure something like Change Data Capture (CDC) and to make your OCI application a subscriber to changes to the table, but that also requires a one-time effort to configure CDC.

Comment: Whoa, that's really cool. I've missed that pseudocolumn. but I wouldn't use CDC... way too complex for his purposes. I'd use DCN (Database Change notification).

Comment: What is a row is deleted? How can I find out?

Answer (score 66):

I'm really late to this party but here's how I did it:

```
SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(MAX(ora_rowscn)) from myTable;
```

It's close enough for my purposes.

Comment: Works as long as last update to your table hasn't been too long ago. Else you get an error, so it's safest to first do a:
left join sys.smon_scn_time tiemposmax
  on myTable.ora_rowscn <= tiemposmax.scn
and then apply SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP to your table's ora_rowscn if and only if there's a match. Otherwise you can display the SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(MIN(SCN)) from sys.smon_scn_time as the earliest date the table was modified before.

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT * FROM all_tab_modifications;
```

Comment: This would require you to gather statistics on the table first, since it only shows changes after the last gather statistics.

Comment: This looks like a nice idea but actually it has many caveats: not all DML are guaranteed to be reflected, it is not instant and may require to run `dbms_stats.flush_database_monitoring_info` to make it up-to-date, after statistics gathering there is no entry in this view and also **it already records the changes before commit**.

Answer (score 12):

Ask your DBA about auditing.  He can start an audit with a simple command like :

```
AUDIT INSERT ON user.table
```

Then you can query the table USER_AUDIT_OBJECT to determine if there has been an insert on your table since the last export.

google for Oracle auditing for more info...

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is the way It's Supposed To Be Done.

Sadly, "Asking the DBA" tend's to be rather complicated. They are really paranoid about changing stuff. I do understand them. If anything is wrong with this db, things tend to get ugly.

Answer (score 6):

Could you run a checksum of some sort on the result and store that locally?  Then when your application queries the database, you can compare its checksum and determine if you should import it?

It looks like you may be able to use the [ORA_HASH](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions107.htm) function to accomplish this.

**Update:** Another good resource: [10g’s ORA_HASH function to determine if two Oracle tables’ data are equal](http://tonguc.wordpress.com/2008/03/06/10gs-ora_hash-function-to-determine-if-two-oracle-tables-data-are-equal/)

Comment: Sounds interesting.  Can you include an example of creating a hash for a table?

Answer (score 5):

Oracle can watch tables for changes and when a change occurs can execute a callback function in PL/SQL or OCI. The callback gets an object that's a collection of tables which changed, and that has a collection of rowid which changed, and the type of action, Ins, upd, del.

So you don't even go to the table, you sit and wait to be called. You'll only go if there are changes to write.

It's called [Database Change Notification](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dcn.htm). It's much simpler than CDC as Justin mentioned, but both require some fancy admin stuff. The good part is that neither of these require changes to the APPLICATION.

The caveat is that CDC is fine for high volume tables, DCN is not.

Comment: FWIW, I've recently discovered CQN (i.e. CDN) is not supported on 12c's PDBs. Hopefully it will be in the future.

Answer (score 5):

If the auditing is enabled on the server, just simply use

```
SELECT *
FROM ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ()
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add a trigger on insert, update, delete that sets a value in another table to sysdate.

When you run application, it would read the value and save it somewhere so that the next time it is run it has a reference to compare.

Would you consider that "Special Admin Stuff"?

It would be better to describe what you're actually doing so you get clearer answers.

Answer (score 1):

How long does the batch process take to write the file?  It may be easiest to let it go ahead and then compare the file against a copy of the file from the previous run to see if they are identical.

Comment: That's the problem: I don't just write the data but I need to process it in a complicated way. This takes several hours and this what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

If any one is still looking for an answer they can use [Oracle Database Change Notification](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28815) feature coming with Oracle 10g. It requires `CHANGE NOTIFICATION` system privilege. You can register listeners when to trigger a notification back to the application.

Answer (score -6):

Please use the below statement

```
select * from all_objects ao where ao.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'  and ao.OWNER = 'YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME'
```

Comment: you addressed the question to the different direction