# Oracle: How to find the timestamp of the last update (any table) within a schema?

Tags: sql, oracle, schema, timestamp, sql-update

There is an Oracle database schema (very small in data, but still about 10-15 tables). It contains a sort of configuration (routing tables).

There is an application that have to poll this schema from time to time. Notifications are not to be used.

If no data in the schema were updated, the application should use its current in-memory version.

If any table had any update, the application should reload all the tables into memory.

What would be the most effective way to check the whole schema for update since a given key point (time or transaction id)?

I am imagined Oracle keeps an transaction id per schema. Then there should be a way to query such an ID and keep it to compare with at next poll.

I've found this question, where such an pseudo-column exists on a row level:

[How to find out when an Oracle table was updated the last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265122/how-to-find-out-when-an-oracle-table-was-updated-the-last-time)

I would think something similar exists on a schema level.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you talking about changes to the schema itself (DDL) or updates to the data in the tables?

Comment: Changes to data, sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<strike>I'm not aware of any such functionality in Oracle.</strike> See below.

The best solution I can come up with is to create a trigger on each of your tables that updates a one-row table or [context](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_5002.htm) with the current date/time. Such triggers could be at the table-level (as opposed to row-level), so they wouldn't carry as much overhead as most triggers.

Incidentally, Oracle can't keep a transaction ID per schema, as one transaction could affect multiple schemas. It might be possible to use V$ views to track a transaction back to the objects it affected, but it wouldn't be easy and it would almost certainly perform poorer than the trigger scheme.

It turns out, if you have 10g, you can use Oracle's flashback functionality to get this information.  However, you'd need to enable flashback (which carries some overhead of it's own) and the query is ridiculously slow (presumably because it's not really intended for this use):

```
select max(commit_timestamp) 
from FLASHBACK_TRANSACTION_QUERY 
where table_owner = 'YOUR_SCHEMA' 
      and operation in ('INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE','MERGE')
```

---

In order to avoid locking issues in the "last updated" table, you'd probably want to put that update into a procedure that uses an autonomous transaction, such as:

```
create or replace procedure log_last_update as
pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
   update last_update set update_date = greatest(sysdate,update_date);
   commit;
end log_last_update;
```

This will cause your application to serialize to some degree: each statement that needs to call this procedure will need to wait until the previous one finishes. The "last updated" table may also get out of sync, because the update on it will persist even if the update that activated the trigger is rolled back. Finally, if you have a particularly long transaction, the application could pick up the new date/time before the transaction is completed, defeating the purpose. The more I think about this, the more it seems like a bad idea.

---

The better solution to avoid these issues is just to insert a row from the triggers.  This would not lock the table, so there wouldn't be any serialization and the inserts wouldn't need to be made asynchronously, so they could be rolled back along with the actual data (and wouldn't be visible to your application until the data is visible as well). The application would get the max, which should be very fast if the table is indexed (in fact, this table would be an ideal candidate for an index-organized table). The only downside is that you'd want a job that runs periodically to clean out old values, so it didn't grow too large.

Comment: Good ideas.  But remember if you're using flashback you'll have to pay close attention to your retention settings.  Even then, data changes could get lost if the server restarts.  You may need to use something like Oracle Total Recall to truly guarantee capturing all changes.

Comment: Regarding trigger: with parallel updates, how can I avoid conflicts when updating that one-row table? Is there a way to say "this update goes outside of the current transaction"?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of the trigger approach. The updates in the current application are not often, and very short (add route, delete route), so the serialized behaviour is not an issue. Out of sync is not issue too: the worst could happen is an extra config reload, which (if happen only occasionally) will not cause any harm. I'll go with the trigger for update first. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**dbms_stats.gather_table_stats** might also help:   http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=607610

```
   4. Statistics is considered to be stale, when the change is over 10% of current rows. 
   (As of 11g, this value can be customized per objects. Cool feature)


    .
    . 
    .

exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'T_STAT');

select * from sys.dba_tab_modifications where table_name = 'T_STAT';
No row selected

select stale_stats from sys.dba_tab_statistics where table_name = 'T_STAT';
NO

insert into t_stat select rownum from all_objects where rownum <= 20;

select * from sys.dba_tab_modifications where table_name = 'T_STAT';
No rows selected <-- Oops
select stale_stats from sys.dba_tab_statistics where table_name = 'T_STAT';
NO  <-- Oops

exec dbms_stats.flush_database_monitoring_info;

select * from sys.dba_tab_modifications where table_name = 'T_STAT';
TABLE_OWNER TABLE_NAME  PARTITION_NAME  SUBPARTITION_NAME   INSERTS UPDATES DELETES TIMESTAMP   TRUNCATED   DROP_SEGMENTS
UKJA        T_STAT      20  0   0   2008-01-18 PM 11:30:19  NO  0

select stale_stats from sys.dba_tab_statistics where table_name = 'T_STAT';
YES
```