# How to find a certain field's timestamp of the last update (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to find the date of updating a certain field (not the table as a whole). I just need to find when this value has been updated to the current value (last update). I am using Oracle 10g. I found some useful posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775671/oracle-how-to-find-the-timestamp-of-the-last-update-any-table-within-a-schema) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265122/how-to-find-out-when-an-oracle-table-was-updated-the-last-time) but they discuss table update rather than particular values. Is that possible without referring to the DBA ??

Comment: You can determine when a row is updated, not a specific column (field).

Comment: Try using ROWSCN .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520995/understanding-the-ora-rowscn-behavior-in-oracle

Comment: @OldProgrammer How can I do that ? and does not specify which value in the row has been updated ?

Comment: hi @hawk was this answer helpful to solve your problem? If not please add what was not successful to your question. When the answer helped you, can you accept it by clicking the hollow green check mark next to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle it is not possible directly using SQL, unless you know in advanced that this question would be asked and had taken measures such as a trigger or configuring auditing for this type of issue.

However, when absolutely needed, you can also revert to the archived redo log files. Most production database archive their redo log files (with almost all transaction information) in the file system and save them for some time. The archived redo log files are typically used to restore the database to a previous or current situation, starting from a backup somewhere in the past and then rolling forward the transactions.

Archived redo log files contain the information asked. You can use their contents using Oracle Logminer. LogMiner is available on 10g. See [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/logminer.htm)