# how to check last connected user,time in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

please let me know 
How to Find When the User Last Logged into the Database?
please let me know how to check this information  with the command.

Answer (score 4):

Enable auditing.

Then audit connects - very easy command

```
audit connect
```

[Docs Link Here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/dbseg/configuring-audit-policies.html#GUID-22CDB667-5AA2-4051-A262-FBD0236763CB)

Then do some connects.

Then query sys.dba_audit_session -

```
SELECT
    username,
    timestamp
FROM
    sys.dba_audit_session
WHERE
    username = 'HR' -- the user you care about
    AND action_name = 'LOGON'
ORDER BY
    timestamp DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY -- in 11g or older just also say where rownum < 2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select username, machine, to_char(logon_time,'HH:MM:SS')
from v$session 
where username='SYS'  <-- username
```

Comment: let me know the last modified (DML opearation)

Comment: Check these links: [How to find out when an Oracle table was updated the last time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/265507/10457877) and [How to get a last DML operation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115067)